# Error inflating class of binary xml file in Cardview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, logcat

This is my Java file which is not opening

```
package com.impwala.impwala;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

public class hschome extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hschome);

        CardView card1 = findViewById(R.id.card1);
        CardView card2 = findViewById(R.id.card2);
        CardView card3 = findViewById(R.id.card3);
        CardView card4 = findViewById(R.id.card4);
        CardView card5 = findViewById(R.id.card5);

        card1.setOnClickListener(this);
        card2.setOnClickListener(this);
        card3.setOnClickListener(this);
        card4.setOnClickListener(this);
        card5.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.card1:
                openActivity();
                break;
            case R.id.card2:
                openActivity2();
                break;
            case R.id.card3:
                openActivity3();
                break;
            case R.id.card4:
                openActivity4();
                break;
            case R.id.card5:
                openActivity5();
                break;
        }
    }
    public void openActivity(){
        Intent intent1=new Intent(this,Math.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
    public void openActivity2(){
        Intent intent2=new Intent(this,Physics.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
    }
    public void openActivity3(){
        Intent intent3=new Intent(this,Biology.class);
        startActivity(intent3);
    }
    public void openActivity4(){
        Intent intent4=new Intent(this,Chemistry.class);
        startActivity(intent4);

    }
    public void openActivity5() {
        Intent intent5;
        intent5 = new Intent(this, English.class);
        startActivity(intent5);
    }
}
```

This is the XML file of my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:context=".hschome">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="2"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textGrid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/hsc_board"
                android:textColor="#8b1a1a "
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
            android:rowCount="1"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="30dp"
            >

            <!-- ROW 1  -->
            <!-- COLUMN 1  -->



            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="30dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/color1" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <TextView
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:text="@string/mathematics"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- COLUMN 2  -->

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@drawable/gradient2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="30dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/color1" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <TextView
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:text="@string/physics"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



            <!-- ROW 2  -->
            <!-- COLUMN 1  -->

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="30dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/color1" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="@string/biology"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- COLUMN 2  -->

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="30dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/color1" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="@string/chemistry"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            <!-- ROW 3  -->
            <!-- COLUMN 1  -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="30dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/color1" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <TextView
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:text="@string/english"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- COLUMN 2  -->



        </GridLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</GridLayout>
```

And this the build file of my app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.impwala.impwala"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
   buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'


    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0-alpha02'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1"
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'


    //add library
    implementation 'gr.pantrif:easy-android-splash-screen:0.0.1'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'


    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The error I am getting in Logcat is very hard and not getting solved. I don't know what is the problem. But When I open the file it crashes.
It crashes with the message showing the error at the line from java file of linking of layout and java file. Line no. 15 or 14 of something in my case.
I don't know if the problem is of onclicklistener or ANdroidJUnit or deprecated attribute or cardview or anything else.

here is the error I am getting

```
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tencent.ig--bBLUItSBvy1ZOEIt--4Tw==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.tencent.ig--bBLUItSBvy1ZOEIt--4Tw==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:171)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:228)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:340)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5497)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:474)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:308)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:853)
2020-08-30 10:48:19.230 2893-2893/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tencent.ig--bBLUItSBvy1ZOEIt--4Tw==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.tencent.ig--bBLUItSBvy1ZOEIt--4Tw==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:171)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:228)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:340)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5497)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:474)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:308)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:853)
2020-08-30 10:48:19.288 5838-5868/? E/MiuiSysImpl: READ_PHONE_STATE permission not granted
2020-08-30 10:48:19.347 5838-5857/? E/MiuiSysImpl: READ_PHONE_STATE permission not granted
2020-08-30 10:48:19.452 5904-5904/? E/ctivate.servic: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-08-30 10:48:19.475 5863-5903/? E/##XLogger##: com.miui.cloudservice.cloudcontrol.@IPV6@SourceFile:2, thread:96480--cloud config is not expired , request canceled
2020-08-30 10:48:19.484 5926-5926/? E/com.xiaomi.xms: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-08-30 10:48:19.638 5904-5904/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.display.type"
2020-08-30 10:48:19.656 5948-5948/? E/.android.camer: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-08-30 10:48:19.657 5926-5926/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.display.type"
2020-08-30 10:48:19.863 5904-5942/? E/MiuiSysImpl: READ_PHONE_STATE permission not granted
2020-08-30 10:48:19.884 5948-5948/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.display.type"
2020-08-30 10:48:20.006 5904-5931/? E/MiuiSysImpl: READ_PHONE_STATE permission not granted
2020-08-30 10:48:20.046 5948-5948/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.boot.hwversion"
2020-08-30 10:48:20.108 5987-5987/? E/com.android.mm: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-08-30 10:48:20.213 5948-6013/? E/CAM_WatermarkMiSysUtils: isFileExist NO Permission!!!!
2020-08-30 10:48:20.213 5948-6013/? E/CAM_WatermarkMiSysUtils: isFileExist NO Permission!!!!
2020-08-30 10:48:20.240 5987-5987/? E/com.android.mm: Dex checksum does not match for dex: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar.Expected: 3079070930, actual: 1845989642
2020-08-30 10:48:20.320 5987-5987/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.display.type"
2020-08-30 10:48:20.920 6095-6095/? E/iui.micloudsyn: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-08-30 10:48:21.112 6095-6095/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.display.type"
2020-08-30 10:48:21.125 5987-6083/? E/RcsService: initMaap
    java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider chatbotinfo for user 10; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1953)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1921)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1871)
        at android.content.IContentService$Stub$Proxy.registerContentObserver(IContentService.java:849)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:1988)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:1977)
        at com.juphoon.helper.RcsChatbotManager.init(SourceFile:3)
        at com.xiaomi.rcs.tool.RcsService.initMaap(SourceFile:2)
        at com.xiaomi.rcs.tool.RcsService.access$500(SourceFile:1)
        at com.xiaomi.rcs.tool.RcsService$2.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.content.ContentService.registerContentObserver(ContentService.java:340)
        at android.content.IContentService$Stub.onTransact(IContentService.java:76)
        at com.android.server.content.ContentService.onTransact(ContentService.java:262)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:726)
2020-08-30 10:48:21.392 2893-3047/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2020-08-30 10:48:22.044 6125-6125/? E/.android.camer: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-08-30 10:48:22.167 6125-6125/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.display.type"
2020-08-30 10:48:22.273 6125-6125/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.boot.hwversion"
2020-08-30 10:48:22.435 6125-6142/? E/CAM_WatermarkMiSysUtils: isFileExist NO Permission!!!!
2020-08-30 10:48:22.435 6125-6142/? E/CAM_WatermarkMiSysUtils: isFileExist NO Permission!!!!
2020-08-30 10:48:22.973 5755-5755/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.impwala.impwala, PID: 5755
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.impwala.impwala/com.impwala.impwala.hschome}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #92: Binary XML file line #92: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1839)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6861)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #92: Binary XML file line #92: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #92: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:651)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.impwala.impwala.hschome.onCreate(hschome.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7232)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7221)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2964)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1839)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6861)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Can't find ColorStateList from drawable resource ID #0x7f07006e
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadColorStateList(ResourcesImpl.java:1054)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1055)
2020-08-30 10:48:22.973 5755-5755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:551)
        at androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.<init>(CardView.java:127)
        at androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.<init>(CardView.java:117)
            ... 32 more
```

please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Following resource in drawble. The error might be present in that gradient or the resource it self not available
`android:background="@drawable/gradient"`

Comment: Yeah. That solved my problem. Actually the gradient file was all okay. But when I tried commenting on the gradient file, I found I have accidently put                                                                                  app:cardBackgroundColor="@drawable/gradient2" in one of my card file. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the `"@color/color1"` are created